# I want connect my firebase information with my mail

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just created a contact form and I use firebase realtime database to get the information of the website visitor who want to contact me.

and now I want receive an email with the information form firebase each time a visitor send a contact submission from the web site.

how can I connect firebase realtime database with my email?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you achieve your desired functionality.

One way of doing is by using Firebase Cloud Functions. You state that you want to receive an email after a user persists information to firebase Realtime database. I suggest have a thorough look at [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) and look under firebase real-time database triggers. These functions get executed or are triggered after an operation(delete, update, write) occurs within the database. Also have a look at [Firebase Functions Send Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44445624/cloud-functions-for-firebase-send-email-onwrite) for how to implement the email sending part.